# VMware - Protecting a virtual machine ovf/ova

Tags: virtualization, esxi

I am working on vcenter server 5 standard. I am generating an OVA using vsphere client. Since OVA is a tar file, unauthorized user can get hold of the software. So i am looking at solutions to prevent this.

I could protect the tar file by using gcrypt however it will involve additional step of decrypting before deploying in vcenter or workstation.

Are there any other means to protect the OVA while still retaining the simplicity of deployment ?

I see that vcenter is generating OVA using OVF version 1.0 however OVF version 2.0 does have defined something for package protection.

There does not seem to be information available on web about VMWare product that can generate 2.0 OVF...

Any clues regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the OVF on an encrypted volume, using something like [encfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) or [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Unfortunately that does not seem to be an option. One of the means OVF would be distributed is over CD and unauthorized user can get hands on it....If there is a way to protect the original source that would be ideal ... instead of encrypting after OVF is transferred onto CD, it would be safe on any transfer media ..

Comment: It could be decrypted and copied to a CD even if you used gcrypt - a solution you suggested was acceptable but too convoluted in your original question.

Comment: But this does not prevent somebody getting hold of the media (CD)...Hence i thought it would be better to prevent the OVA when it is being generated instead of applying preventing mechanisms after the fact..I think OVF2.0 does define secure distribution by encryption, however i am unable to find any vmware tools that support OVF2.0..